# Is there any way to convert String into Dart functional code?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting conditions in an string.

For example: `String conditions = "gender == 1 && gender == 3";`

I want to convert it into If Conditional statement.

like `if(gender == 1 && gender == 3) {  }`

How can I parse that string ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [function_tree](https://pub.dev/packages/function_tree) package to convert string to expression.

```
String conditions = "gender == 1 && gender == 3";
if(conditions.interpret()) {  }
```